# AWS CLI: Modify VPC on running instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

Using AWS CLI, is there any way to change the VPC of a running instance ?

I have a running instance in a region with a network that has private ip that is using `subnet-id` from `vpc-id`. I would like to be able to change the private IP to another that belongs `subnet-id-2` from `vpc-2`

Is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: No, you can't

You have to create new instance and assign the proper IP address to the new instance in new VPC.